# Flot time series not drawing line

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am trying to plot a line graph, using timestamps from the past 24 hours (plotting data for each 1 hour interval), to show a decreasing and increasing value in flot.  When I set my minTickSize, min, and max values, the line no longer plots.

Complete code (also in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71mkky3z/1/)):

```
$(function () {

    var d = [
        [1443903422000, 4994],
        [1443903429000, 4993],
        [1443910918000, 4999]
    ];
    var epochT = (new Date).getTime(); // time right now in js epoch

    $.plot("#placeholder", [d], {
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            timeformat: "%I:%M",
            minTickSize: [1, "hour"],
            min: epochT - 2 * 86400000,
            max: epochT,
            timezone: "browser",
        },
        series: {
            lines: {
                show: true
            },
            points: {
                show: true
            },
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true,
        },
    });
});
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to resolving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yout timestamps are in seconds not microseconds like JavaScript needs it (see [here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data) in the documentation). Multiplying by thousand (and shifting the min value because it already cuts off the chart) leads to this [updated fiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/71mkky3z/3/).

Changes to your code:

```
var d = [[1443903422000,4994], [1443903429000,4993], [1443910918000,4999]];

min: epochT - 2*86400000,
```

Comment: Ah, It looks like I linked to the wrong JSFiddle.  I updated the link.  I tried adding min/max/minTickSize and to no avail.  Thanks!

Comment: Yep, that was it!  I was assuming I was working with seconds and not microseconds.  Such a silly mistake on my part, and thank you for pointing me to the documentation!  Thanks for your help!